# Change a ' , ' by a ' . ' in csv file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

Hello I want to replace the comma in a column of an excel file with points in my python program and I want my column to be a list.

My code:

```
id1= row[1]
id4 = []          
absence = []


for row in range(1,360):
      absence.append(float(feuille_1.cell_value(row, 10)))
      id4.append(id1)


result2 = {}
    for name2 in set(id4):
    result2[name2] = 0


for i in range(len(id4)):
      hours2 = float(absence[i])
      name2 = id4[i]
      result2[name2] += hours2

     print(result2)
```

I have this following error :

```
absence.append(float(feuille_1.cell_value(row, 10)))
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

I show you my exel file : 
[image: My Excel file]

And i want to tranform all of my column to an float to execute my code.
The specific column that i want to deal with is :
[image: specific column]

Comment: Perhaps you would like to fix the indentation of your code. What you have posted is unrunnable.

Comment: `feuille_1.cell_value(row, 10)` -> `feuille_1.cell_value(row, 10).replace(",", ".")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to convert a empty value. Make Try and Except , check if the cellule is empty or no .

Comment: I will try that

Comment: for i in range(5,len(id4)): @samuelL-M

Answer (score 0):

To deal with excel file or csv in python, a good tool to use is the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) package. It allows you to create a so called DataFrame with the same number of columns than your excel file and do all kind of operations on it. You can also specify the decimal delimiter when opening the csv file. 
For example if your delimiter is a ';' and the decimal delimiter is ',' open your csv using:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('path/to/your/csv/file', decimal=',', delimiter=';')
```

Then in `df` you will have your excel data. 
to select one column (`myCol` in the following  you just have to do :

```
val = df.myCol.tolist()
```

and the values of your column will be stored in a list.

Comment: I see that, but pandas is more convenient if you want to retrieve data in your csv. It also have a function to load excel files. You could read your column using much less code (and less potential mistake)

Answer (score 0):

I know where is my mistake it's because the list begin at :

```
['', '', '', '', 'Jours', '1,00',
```

And i want that she begin at ;

```
 ['1,00', '2,00', '1,00', '1,00', '1,00', '1,00'
```

Comment: If you use pandas you could use the skiprows parameter inside the read_excel method